# Get PST file from every user and sort them into size

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Hey Guys I have a task to do but I don't have any plan how to execute it. There are users in `c:\users` and I have to get all `.pst` files in der directory and sum them together. And at the end have to sort them in a table, so that we can see who uses the most disk space for `.pst` files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to "at least" attempt to write something?

Anyways, you can start with something along these lines:

```
$path = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\users -Filter "*.pst" -Recurse | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Fullname

For($i=0; $i -lt $path.Count; $i++){
[pscustomobject] @{
    PSTsFound = $path[$i]
    }
}
```

With some help from Pat Richard:
(UC Unleashed)

```
function Get-PstFiles {

  [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess = $True)]
  param(
        [Parameter(Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline = $True, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $True, Mandatory = $False)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$path,
        [Parameter(Position = 1, ValueFromPipeline = $True, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $True, Mandatory = $False)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$filter = "*.pst",
        [Parameter(Position = 2, ValueFromPipeline = $True, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $True, Mandatory = $False)]
        [ValidatePattern(".csv")]
        [string]$file
  )
  Begin{
      $PSTFiles = @()
  }
  Process{
        Get-ChildItem $path -recurse -Filter $filter | ? {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $False} | % {
            $obj = New-Object PSObject
            $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Directory $_.DirectoryName
            $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Name $_.Name
            $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty "Size in MB" ([System.Math]::Round(($_.Length/1mb),2))
            $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Owner ((Get-ACL $_.FullName).Owner)
            $PSTFiles += $obj
        }
  }
  end{
        if ($file){
            $PSTFiles | Export-CSV "$file" -NoTypeInformation 
        }else{
            $PSTFiles
        }
  }
}
```

With the Syntax being like so:
`Get-PstFiles [[-path] ] [[-filter] ] [[-file] ] [-WhatIf] [-Confirm] []`

Example: `Get-PstFiles -path C:\Users`